# UNITY Как перенести значение из одного скрипта в другой скрипт?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Уже гуглил как это делать, но ничего не выходит. Также и смотрел этот вопрос на Стэке, но обьяснили очень криво. Вообще не понимаю, что не так. Я хочу взять и перенести значение переменной speed

Первый скрипт объекта под названием **Model**, куда я хочу положить значение переменной **speed**:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ModelAnimation : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody Model;

    void Start()
    {
        Model = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        GameObject Player = GameObject.Find("Player");
        Rigidbody modelSpeed = Model.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        float speed = Player.speed;
    }
}
```

Второй скрипт из объекта под названием **Player**, откуда я хочу взять значение переменной **speed**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMove : MonoBehaviour
{   
    public float speed;
    public float rotate;

    Rigidbody Player;

    void Start()
    {
        Player = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") + 1.5f;

        Player.transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * moveVertical * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        Player.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * moveHorizontal * rotate * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Мне пока самое главное хотя бы вывести это значение, чтобы убедиться, что всё работает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Объясню попроще.
Если например вы говорите маме или жене

> Иду в гости к другу.

для начала надо ей объяснить кто такой друг. Для этого вы ей говорите:

> Мой друг - Сергей, живёт в ... .

---

Примерно тоже самое происходит тут.
Скрипту `ModelAnimation` вы говорите так:

> Иду в гости к другу - попросить у него `speed`. Скрипт `PlayerMove` мой друг, живёт в ... .

:-)

---

А теперь на деле.

Скрипт выглядит таким -

```cs
public class ModelAnimation: MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializedField] private PlayerMove _PlayerMoveScript;

    ...

    void Start()
    {
        float SpeedInAnimation = _PlayerMoveScript.speed;
    }
}
```

Только не забудьте в конце добавить скрипт через `Inspector`.

[image]

---

П.Н.
Я прикрепил скрипт к объекту под названием `SceneManager`. Вместо этого у вас на картинке должен быть `Player`.

Comment: Обалдеть, спасибо вам большое! Вы самый лучший  Даже и не догадался, что можно вставить этот скрипт в другой объект

Comment: @Endivine пожалуйста 