# Как передать метод в другой класс, в котором находится массив точек (Unity)?

Tags: c#, массивы, unity3d

Я использую ассет DOTween. Мне нужно передать метод, в котором принимает массив точек, в DOpath из другого скрипта.

```
public class BezierCurve : MonoBehaviour
{
    public LineRenderer lineRender;
    public int numPoints = 30;
    public Vector3[] positions = new Vector3 [30];

-------------
public void Dots(Vector3[] positions)
    {
        
        lineRender.GetPositions(positions);
    }
```

В этот скрипт

```
public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour
{

    
    public PathType pathSystem = PathType.CatmullRom;
    
    
    

    void Start()
    {
        BezierCurve bc = new BezierCurve();

        gameObject.transform.DOPath(bc.Dots(?), 31, pathSystem);
        
    }
```

Что нужно записать в скобках?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [UNITY Как перенести значение из одного скрипта в другой скрипт?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1081832/unity-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82)

Answer (score 0):

> `BezierCurve bc = new BezierCurve();`

Не надо вам эта строка. Вместо него:

```cs
public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour
{
    BezierCurve bc; //Прикрепите скрипт через инспектор
    void Start()
    {
        gameObject.transform.DOPath(bc.Dots(bc.positions), 31, pathSystem);
    }
}
```

---

Лучше [прочитайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1081861/324730) как это работает, потому что на такие вопросы ответили множество раз, как другие, так и я.

Comment: Если отвечали много раз, то какой смысл отвечать повторно? Голосуйте за дубликат и все.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Подумал помочь новичку. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но задача не решилась(.

Comment: @diver6ent Ну вообще это неизвестный мне assets, может скажите что именно не получилось?

Comment: ругается на DOpath с transform`om , так скажем, решения не нашел в интернете.  Но поможет тот, кто как раз разбирается в этом ассете

Comment: @diver6ent это всё понятно. Вы ошибку киньте конкретно. Что выдаёт компилятор или Unity как ошибку?

Comment: Мне надо было через linerender.Getpostions получить массив с точками, а потом на dopath передать его
В итоге у меня компилятор говорит что: Трансформ не подходит, (так как я передаю первым массив (а так и надо ) ) нужно передавать первым rigid body. (там не должен быть риджит, DOpath принимает сначала вектор с массивами)

Comment: Сегодня понял (и подсказали), что можно без ассета сделать. Как мне передать этот лайнрендер,гетпосишн в выстрле (метод где у меня происходит выстрел)

Comment: @diver6ent Для этого создайте отдельный вопрос, но я в этом не разбираюсь, не могу помочь.