# Взаимодействие со скриптом из другого скрипта

Tags: c#, unity3d, scripts

Я пишу игру на юнити, возникла необходимость изменять значения одного скрипта, из другого, я знаю, что это делается с помощью делегатов, и проблем с компонентами типа Rigidbody не возникает. Но тот скрипт самописный, и я не знаю, ак правильно это организовать. Есть какие-то мысли?
P.S. я приложил скрин, какие параметры необходимо изменить в скрипте.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD1: я добавил в скрипт вот такую строчку, следуя указаниям из вопроса, на который вы мне указали.

```
    public DialogInput script;
```

И получил вот эту ошибку
Assets/Scripts/disable_saydialog.cs(7,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DialogInput' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
UPD2: https://pastebin.com/cYXMLJPX ссылка на скрипт Dialog Input

Comment: Не надо тут совершенно никаких делегатов. Достаточно знать что такое class и то что все скрипты в Unity представляют из себя class-ы.

Comment: я это знаю, но не понимаю, как это можно проецировать на мой вопрос

Comment: Покажите скрипт `Dialog Input`. Это ваш скрипт?

Comment: Нет, скрипт относится к плагину, скачанному из ассет стора

Comment: в UPD2 я добавил ссылку на pastebin со скриптом, можете посмотреть

Comment: Надо было в начале писать что это скрипт из Assets Store. С этим Asset-ом не встречался. В таком случае либо посмотрите в справке, либо подождите может кто-то знает решение в нашем сайте. Да ещё удалил тревогу, вопрос не дубликат.

Comment: хорошо, спасибо

Comment: ну вообще можно через GameObject.GetComponent<скрипт>().переменная

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [UNITY Как перенести значение из одного скрипта в другой скрипт?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1081832/unity-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82)

Comment: Виктор, прочитайте пожалуйста сообщения выше, уже были у людей такие подозрения)

Comment: Methorn, не могли бы вы привести пример? Пожалуйста)

Comment: Ссылки лично у меня сломаны, не учитывая их, в чем проблема использовать GetComponent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

класс `DialogInput` находится в `namespace Fungus`
поэтому в скрипте, где вы пишите

```
public DialogInput script;
```

нужно в самом верху добавить

```
using Fungus;
```

тогда ошибка `Assets/Scripts/disable_saydialog.cs(7,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DialogInput' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` уйдёт.

Это нужно делать во всех скриптах, где вы используете ссылки на `DialogInput`, через `GetComponent<>` или как-то еще, иначе вы будете получать ошибку, как выше. Так как нужный класс будет просто-напросто не виден.

Более подробно про пространства имен тут:
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите из первого скрипта изменить переменную во втором скрипте, то просто возьмите объект, на котором висит второй скрипт, у него получите компонент - сам второй скрипт, а там уже и переменную. В первом скрипте это выглядит примерно так:

```
GameObject_со_вторым_скриптом.GetComponent<Название_второго_скрипта>().название_переменной
```

Переменная естественно должна быть public.
Если я что-то в вашем вопросе понял неправильно, напишите.

Comment: Не могли бы вы привести примеры на самом скрипте Dialog Input, собственно, это и есть главная задача вопроса